# Simple for-loop and print

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm working in Python 2.7

I am doing some very basic exercises and this is my code:

```
def main():
    print """Program computes the value of an investment 
    carried 10 years into the future"""
    principal = input("Enter the principal: ")
    apr = input("Provide (in decimal format) the annual percentage rate: ")
    for i in range(10):
        principal = principal * (1 + apr)
        print "The value in 10 years will be: $", principal

main()
```

The code is working but I want the output to be only the final result. What I am getting now is all the 10 steps of the loop being printed one after another.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can move the print statement out of the loop:

```
for i in range(10):
    principal = principal * (1 + apr)

print "The value in 10 years will be: $", principal
```

This means the value of principal will be calculated inside the for loop, and then the value of principal will be printed (only once) as it is outside the for loop.

Answer (score 8):

Python is indentation sensitive; that is, it uses the indentation level of a block of text to determine what lines of code are inside a loop (rather than {} curly brackets, for example).

So in order to move the print statement out of the loop (as in the previous answer), just decrease the indent

Answer (score 4):

Move the print outside and after the loop. Or simply avoid it entirely:

```
principal *= (1 + apr)**10
print print "The value in 10 years will be: $", principal
```

Answer (score 3):

Your print statement is inside the for loop. It needs to be outside the loop.

You can do that by reducing the indentation of the print statement, thus bringing it outside the loop.

```
for i in range(10):
        principal = principal * (1 + apr)
print "The value in 10 years will be: $", principal #See the indentation here
```

Answer (score 1):

Just dedent the print statement to put it outside the loop.

Moreover you should consider changing "input" to "raw_input" and wrapping it around "int()"

```
principal = raw_input("Enter the principal: ")
try:
    principal = int(principal)
except ValueError:
    print "Warning ! You did not input an integer !"
```